# How to remove the author from uploaded PDF?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have clients uploading PDF's via a form.  I would like to have the upload clear the properties of the PDF, so that future users will see no trace of the author.

To be more specific, the properties are those one see when the PDF is downloaded, right click, and select "properties".  You can then view the PDF properties, such as title, author, subject, and keywords.   I haven't found a way to access these within Google Docs, but they are regularly used by e-readers to identify the PDFs.  I would like to replace or clear these fields.

UPDATE: Almost 4 years later, and I still need a solution for this. Offering a bounty.  I would welcome any work-arounds or other tricks to remove the author name.  Perhaps it is not editing the properties directly, but messing with a blob or something.  (Note: Text formatting in the PDF must be preserved.)

Comment: What properties would you like to clear. Is it the properties shown on the form after uploading or something else? Please write in detail if you expect an answer from the community.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear.  I've updated on your recommendation. Thank you!

Comment: I'm guessing this is not the kind of solution you are looking for, but you could probably use an external web service (e.g. http://www.aspose.com/products/pdf/cloud) to process the PDF and then upload.

Comment: Is the upload form a form you can manipulate or work around something or is it a form of some provider you have no direct access to?

Comment: @sew It's important that the files stay in drive, but an external service could work.  Will look a bit into it.

Comment: @Mr.Generation - I built the form from the ground up, using Google App Script.  Have as much access as that allows.

Answer (score 5):

There are no such options Google Apps Script or Google Docs/Drive API. You may file a feature request [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request%20from%20user).